# Group acts strongly primitive iff point stabilizer is maximal subsemigroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, group-actions

If a group $G$ acts on some set $\Omega$, then we have a natural action on $\Omega\times\Omega$ given by $(\alpha,\beta)^x := (\alpha^x, \beta^x)$. If $\Delta \subseteq \Omega\times\Omega$ is some orbit of this action on $\Omega\times\Omega$, then we could look at the graph given by vertex set $\Omega$ and edge set $\Delta$, this graph is called the orbital graph of $\Delta$. One characterisation of primitivity is that $G$ acts primitive iff for each orbital its corresponding graph is connected. If all orbital graphs are strongly connected (i.e. between any two vertexes there exists a directed path), then we say that $G$ acts *strongly primitive*.

I want to show:

> Suppose that the group $G$ acts transitively on $\Omega$ and let $G_{\alpha}$ be a point stabilizer. Show that $G$ is strongly primitive if and only if there is no subset $T$ with the properties $G_{\alpha} \subset T \subset G$ and $TT \subseteq T$ (in other words, $G_{\alpha}$ is a maximal subsemigroup of $G$).

I am stuck with this, has anybody hints how to show this? One Lemma concerning strong primitivity I have at hand is:

*Lemma:* Let $G$ be a group acting primitively on $\Omega$.

(i) The orbital graph of some orbit $\Delta$ is strongly connected iff
it contains a nontrivial directed cycle,

(ii) If for each pair $\alpha, \beta$ there exists $z \in G$ with a cycle of finite length containing both $\alpha$ and $\beta$, then $G$ is strongly primitive,

(iii) If $G$ is periodic (in particular finite), then $G$ is strongly primitive.

Maybe this might be of help?

Comment: For one direction, if one of the directed orbital graphs is not strongly onnected, then let $\Gamma$ be the set of points that you can reach from $\alpha$ with a directed path, and $T = \{g \in G \mid \alpha^g \in \Gamma \}$. Clearly $G_\alpha \subset T \subset G$ with strict containments, and it is not too hard to show thatt $TT = T$. I haven't thought about the converse, but I expect it is similar.

Comment: Thank you for you comment, that definitely brought me on the right track! Now I also could prove the converse, but contrary to what you said I had not found a way to use a similar construction, instead I used an induction over paths, essentially showing that if $T$ contains $G_{\alpha}$ properly, then we must have $T = G$. It uses the property $\alpha^g = \alpha^t \Leftrightarrow g \in G_{\alpha}t \subset T$ for $t \in T$. If you have a different solution I would be interested, maybe you might write an answer (so I can accept), if you do not want I consider writing my proof as an answer.